# Emoji not dynamically appearing correctly in button

Tags: android, kotlin, unicode, android-button, emoji

I'm trying to add an emoji character next to the text in my `Button`, but for some reason it only appears in plain white and does not appear as the official Android emoji character. Does anyone know what has gone wrong and how to fix this problem?

NB: I do not want to use any Drawables.

**Expected appearance**

[image]

**Current appearance**

[image]

**XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button" 
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Class**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        my_button.text = "\u2642 Hello World"
    }
}
```

Comment: Rendering of emoji depends on the phone.You should look at emoji compat library here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat It can be helpful for you. If it doesn't work as you want, you should use a drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the fully-qualified form of the emoji (emoji style instead of text style) by appending: `U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16`

```
mButton.text = "\u2642\uFE0F Hello World"
```

[emoji-test.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/emoji-test.txt)

```
# subgroup: gender
2640 FE0F                                  ; fully-qualified     # ♀️ female sign
2640                                       ; unqualified         # ♀ female sign
2642 FE0F                                  ; fully-qualified     # ♂️ male sign
2642                                       ; unqualified         # ♂ male sign
```

[emoji-variation-sequences.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/emoji-variation-sequences.txt)

```
2640 FE0E  ; text style;  # (1.1) FEMALE SIGN
2640 FE0F  ; emoji style; # (1.1) FEMALE SIGN
2642 FE0E  ; text style;  # (1.1) MALE SIGN
2642 FE0F  ; emoji style; # (1.1) MALE SIGN
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set style of button view ,
like changing gravity of view,

```
android:gravity="center"
```

or 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
This can set view as aspect
Hope this will help you!!